# Create a method that generates a prime number of a given size in bits

Tags: java, primes

I need to create a Java method that takes single argument (a number) and produces a prime number of that number of bits.

Sample output:

```
$ primegenerate(1024)
$ 142405175064861448442669284843420489603593930617313976674095914073492903976984848373315014340583589674334422581561784146805278310143147937016874549483037286357105260324082207009125626858996989027805604841776344359158053673248019204338406280932000275573354237039522117150476778214733739382939035838341675795443
```

My problem is trying to code this without using any java in built class. Don't really know where to start. Would appreciate it if someone can point me to the right direction.

I was able to convert a method that checks regular primes using BigInt. Now I need to generate primes given a number of bit such as 1024 bits. All I need is you guys to point me in the right direction and that is part of my research as well.

```
import java.math.*;

public class Prime {

public boolean primeCheck(BigInteger n) //My BigInteger version , returns true if number is Prime, false if not
{
      if (n.intValue()==2) //case n =2, function returns true. 
      { 
        return true;
      }

      for (int i=2;i<=(int)Math.sqrt(n.intValue())+1;i++) //loops through 2 to sqrt(n). 
      { 
        if (n.intValue()%i==0)  //if a divisor is found, its not prime. returns false
        { 
          return false;
        }
      }
      return true; //if all cases are not divisible by n, it is prime.
    }
}
```

Comment: Once you have checked divisibility by two, you only need to check odd numbers.  That will (almost) halve the number of checks you have to make.  You can extend this insight if you think about it.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has two parts.  1) Generate a number of a given bit-size.  2) Check if the number you just generated is prime.  Write code to do each part separately.  Ask back here is you cannot get part of your code to work correctly.